# array_flip of a key value for letter and numbers

Tags: php, arrays, array-flip

I have an array like this

```
array(123=>'c', 125=>'b', 139=>'a', 124=>'c', 135=>'c', 159=>'b');
```

and I want to flip the key/values so that duplicate values become an index for an array.

```
array(
    'a'=>array(139),
    'b'=>array(125, 159),
    'c'=>array(123, 124, 135)
);
```

However, array_flip seems to overwrite the keys and array_chunk only splits it based on number values.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Yes, write your own flip method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function array_flop($array) {
    foreach($array as $k => $v) {
        $result[$v][] = $k;
    }
    return array_reverse($result);
}
```

Comment: Reposting Rob Baillie's answer in function form... His won't throw undefined index errors like yours will either. (won't -1 you, because this **is** a useful answer)

Comment: @scrowler: Didn't "repost" anything. There was no answer displayed when I submitted.  Also, care to show an example execution where there are any notices?

Comment: You're right, couldn't replicate my idea of this producing undefined index errors. I would however suggest that you should `return array_reverse($result);` to get the order the same as the QA.

Answer (score 2):

I think it's going to need you to loop over the array manually.  It really shouldn't be hard though...

```
$flippedArray = array();

foreach( $arrayToFlip as $key => $value ) {

  if ( !array_key_exists( $value, $flippedArray ) {
    $flippedArray[ $value ] = array();
  }
  $flippedArray[ $value ][] = $key;

}
```

Comment: This sounds more like a comment than an answer

Comment: Answer added - accidental save.